# Image Uploader API

Tags: widgets, uploads, media-library, images

I want to create a widget for my theme that will let me upload an image to WP and crop it to a certain size. Can anyone point me to the codex page or a tutorial on how to a bare bone implementation of it?

Answer (score 1):

This tutorial explains basic use of WordPress media uploader.

> http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/creative-coding/how-to-integrate-the-wordpress-media-uploader-in-theme-and-plugin-options

To add image sizes use

```
 <?php add_image_size( $name, $width, $height, $crop ); ?>
```

Read more on this at Codex

> http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_image_size